# as.Date returns NAs

Tags: r, as.date

I have a very simple question, but somehow I can not figure out the problem. I want to convert a character column to a date column, to be able to create a line graph afterwards (date on x-axis, x on y-axis). However, when I try to convert the data column, only NAs are returned. I already tried out many different suggestions provided on other threads, but still it does not work. Any help is highly appreciated!

```
structure(list(Group.1 = c("April 2020", "December 2019", "February 2020", 
"January 2020", "March 2020", "May 2020", "November 2019", "October 2019"
), x = c(115, 163, 184, 102, 251, 58, 154, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
#>         Group.1   x
#> 1    April 2020 115
#> 2 December 2019 163
#> 3 February 2020 184
#> 4  January 2020 102
#> 5    March 2020 251
#> 6      May 2020  58
#> 7 November 2019 154
#> 8  October 2019  10
```

```
login_plot$DATE <- as.Date(login_plot$Group.1, format ="%B %Y")
```

```
structure(list(Group.1 = c("April 2020", "December 2019", "February 2020", 
"January 2020", "March 2020", "May 2020", "November 2019", "October 2019"
), x = c(115, 163, 184, 102, 251, 58, 154, 10), DATE = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

        Group.1   x DATE
1    April 2020 115 <NA>
2 December 2019 163 <NA>
3 February 2020 184 <NA>
4  January 2020 102 <NA>
5    March 2020 251 <NA>
6      May 2020  58 <NA>
7 November 2019 154 <NA>
8  October 2019  10 <NA>
```

Comment: you need to append date to it. `df$Group.1 <- as.Date(paste0(df$Group.1, '1'), "%B %Y %d")`

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!